# JIRA Cloud API - Python timeout

Tags: python-jira

we have recently moved from on-prem to cloud and I'm now getting timeout errors when trying to connect to the new instance using python.  I'm guessing that something somewhere is blocking python from connecting to JIRA Cloud..... but I'm at a loss and google isn't helping.

I can happily connect to the cloud API using:

- browser
- VBA
- Excel Power Query
- Postman

So I know my connection details/token are fine.  My python code follows the basis provided by atlasian as shown below.  There's no server returned error code as the error is that it has exceed the number of retries and has not received a response.

Having got the network guys to fully trace their side, they can see a 502 Bad Gateway error.

I'm clutching at straws now and really dont want to have to move back to VBA as it's just not efficient when python comes with JIRA modules.  It's not my python script but something to do with the JIRA Cloud set up by the looks of it.

```
# This code sample uses the 'requests' library:
# http://docs.python-requests.org
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json

url = "https://your-domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/{issueIdOrKey}"

auth = HTTPBasicAuth("email@example.com", "<api_token>")

headers = {
  "Accept": "application/json"
}

response = requests.request(
   "GET",
   url,
   headers=headers,
   auth=auth
)

print(json.dumps(json.loads(response.text), sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(",", ": ")))
```